# Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Cannot Turn-on the Firewall Error Code 0x80070422

Tags: windows-firewall

When I try to turn-on the Windows firewall, I get the error code 0x80070422 which states "Windows Firewall can't change some of your settings." I could not find any solution on Microsoft website.

I was hoping here someone would know the problem or guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Is the windows firewall service running?

Answer (score 0):

Malware is usually the cause of this, so scan for malware first, [see my post in this link](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533)

If it is clean of malware or you removed malware follow this procedure next.

Perform the following steps and update the computer:

1. Click Start, type Notepad in the Start Search box, and then click Notepad in the Programs list.
2. Copy the following text, and then paste the text into Notepad:

   ```
   sc config wuauserv start= auto
   sc config bits start= auto
   sc config DcomLaunch start= auto
   net stop wuauserv
   net start wuauserv
   net stop bits
   net start bits
   net start DcomLaunch
   ```

   Click File, click Save As, and then type Repair.bat.
3. In the Save as type box, click All Files (*.*).
4. In the Save in box, click Desktop, and then click Save.
5. On the File menu, click Exit.
6. Right click the Repair.bat file that you saved in step 5, and then click Run as administrator. This action starts the required services. If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password, or click Continue.
7. Try to install the updates again. If you can install the updates, delete the Repair.bat file. To delete the Repair.bat file, right-click Repair.bat, click Delete, and then click Yes.

Try enabling the firewall after these steps.

[Source of Information](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/error-code-0x80070422-cant-turn-on-firewall/e5ee6823-98f8-4575-a254-00a038b17e34)

Comment: Thank you for the tip but did not work. I also found the article on Microsoft's website and ran the tests. No luck...

Comment: Did you scan for malware as suggested in my link?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would help, but you could try: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821 as it helped me with a similar issue.

Comment: no did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Open Control Panel and go to Administrative Tools.
Find and run Services.
When Services window opens find Windows Update service and double click it to open its Properties.windows update error
In Windows Update Properties find Startup Type and from the dropdown choose Automatic. Also check the Service status, and if the status isn’t set to Running click the Start button in that section to start it.
Click OK to save your settings and restart your computer